# Testing Library - Testing for logic that depends on CSS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have made this component, which all it does it receive a text (long paragraphs) and the CSS will truncate the text if its over the `lines` prop. If truncated, there is a 'show all' button that will remove the class that is hiding some of the text.

The component itself works great, but want to test it, for really no other reason other then to practice testing.

I have written one test:

```
import { render, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/vue';
import TruncateText from '../TruncateText.vue';

describe('TruncateText', () => {
    it('should have truncate class on mount', async () => {
        const text = 'Super Duper Long Text';
        const { getByText } = render(TruncateText, { props: { text } });
        const pTag = getByText(text);
        expect(pTag).toHaveClass('truncate');
        expect(pTag).toHaveTextContent(text);
    });

    it('container should be truncated', async () => {
        const text =
            'Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt';
        const lines = 2;
        const { getByText } = render(TruncateText, {
            props: { text, lines },
        });

        expect(lastThreeCharacters).toBe('...');
    });
});
```

Any thoughts on how I can write the test to check if some text will be truncated?

Other potential tests are mocking the `click` emit so I can check if class is removed. That should really be enough for this component.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <p
            class="text truncate"
            ref="announcement"
            :style="truncated ? `-webkit-line-clamp:${lines}` : ''"
        >
            {{ text }}
        </p>
        <OBButton
            :text="$t('show-all')"
            class="show-all-button"
            size="x-small"
            v-if="truncated"
            @click="showAll"
        />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            text: {
                type: String,
                required: true,
            },
            lines: {
                type: Number,
                default: 10,
            },
        },
        data() {
            return { truncated: false };
        },
        mounted() {
            this.truncated = this.isOverflown(this.$refs.announcement);
        },
        methods: {
            isOverflown(el) {
                return el.scrollHeight > el.clientHeight || el.scrollWidth > el.clientWidth;
            },
            showAll() {
                this.$refs.announcement.classList.remove('truncate');
                this.truncated = false;
            },
        },
    };
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
    .text {
        white-space: pre-line;
    }
    .truncate {
        display: -webkit-box;
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
        overflow: hidden;
        max-height: 24rem; //hack for IE1
    }
    .show-all-button {
        margin-top: 1rem;
    }
</style
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking at the component, you're doing two things upon clicking the button:

- removing the `truncate` class from the paragraph
- setting `truncated` property to `false`.

I would bind the class to the property, using `:class="{ truncate: truncated }"` and then the only thing in need of testing onclick is that `truncated` has been set to `false` (you don't want to test if Vue works).
This removes the need for your `showAll` to manually remove the class from the paragraph: Vue is data driven => you change the data, Vue manages DOM accordingly.

---

To make it as clear as possible: you should only test the component's logic and nothing else. You're not testing Vue, JavaScript or the browser. You trust that those work (other people are in charge of writing tests for them). So, in order:

- expect `truncated` to have the proper value upon mounting (effectively testing `isOverflown()` provides the expected output in each of the cases you care about)
- when `truncated` is `true` trigger a `click` on the button (no need to expect the button to exist when `truncated` is `true`, as you'd be testing if `v-if` works). After clicking the button, in `$nextTick()` expect `truncated` to be set to `false`.

And here is the list of things you should not test:

- that JavaScript works
- that Vue works (applies `:class` and `:style`, applies `v-if`, etc...)
- that the browser understands and applies `-webkit-line-clamp`
- that your testing library works
- that `showAll` has run after clicking the button (you want to be able to rename the method and your test should still pass if clicking the button sets `truncated` to `false`).

That's about it.

Comment: I am finding the recommended changes won't work in my case. On mount, if the CSS will truncate the text. I then check on the mounted hook with the text overflows or not, at which point I update the `truncated` data property.

I say this because when testing, no amount of text will truncate the text and show the button. Is that something we can explore further?

Comment: There are two ways to go about this. ***a)*** figure out why no amount of text truncates. Could it be because your element doesn't have a set `width` in your tests and it never wraps? or ***b)*** skip testing `isOverflown` entirely. Why? Because you're not really testing your code there, you're testing browser's ability to apply CSS (if it really results into `truncated` being set to correct value). I would personally chose `b)`, set `truncated` to each possible case and test the rest of component code works in each case.

Comment: Worked when I set the data property of truncated to true, which shows the button on mount (but hides it shortly after if truncating is not required). What works, works?

Comment: Don't use `data` to pass the value to the test, because it will be changed by the assignment you have in `mounted`. You want to mount first (so `mounted` does its thing) and then, not caring about what `isOverflow` has set `truncated` to, set `truncated` to whatever you want in this particular test.